# Branch points of $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{P}^1 : z \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(z + \frac{1}{z})$

Tags: riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

**Problem:** find the branch points of the function
$$
f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{P}^1 : z \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\bigg(z + \frac{1}{z}\bigg).
$$

**My try:** The zeros are $i$ and $-i$, but I don't see why $f|V$ (the restriction of $f$ to $V$) is not injective for every neighbourhood $V$ of $\pm i$. I tried rewriting $f(z) = \frac{z^2 + 1}{2z}$ and viewing $f$ as a concatenation of maps,
$$
\mathbb{C} \overset{z^2}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{C} \overset{+1}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{C} \overset{1/(2z)}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{P}^1.
$$
However, this did not help my understanding.

Comment: What is $V$? Maybe the answer you'd like is something as simple as noting $f(i)= f(-i)=0$... then on any path around $i$ or  $-i$, you must have $f(z_0 ) = f(z_1)$ where $z_0 \neq z_1$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: $V$ is just some neighbourhood of $i$ (or $-i$) in $\mathbb{C}$. I try to use the definition that $i$ is a branch point if there is no neighbourhood $V$ of $i$ such that $f|V$ is injective.

Comment: If you want to use that definition, the above proof I've mentioned works.

Comment: @Jeb: there is no intermediate value theorem for complex-valued functions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Cauchy's Integral Formula ( averaging over the path)

Comment: This is still not correct, since $\pm i$ are **not** branching points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f$ **is** injective in small neighbourhoods $V$ of $i$ or $-i$: that $f$ is zero at $\pm i$ is completely irrelevant.
The map $f$ will not be injective in small  neighbourhoods of $a$ iff its derivative is zero there: $f'(a)=0$.
In your case the required two branching  points  are  thus $a_1=1, a_2=-1$ .

Comment: That was the insight my sleepy head was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome,  Math student 020.